# sqlite3_prepare fails with "near "TABLE": syntax error"

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite's compiled statements to insert rows into a table:

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, "INSERT INTO TABLE test VALUES (?,?,?,?)", -1, &stmt, 0);
if( rc!=SQLITE_OK )
    printf("%s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

`sqlite3_prepare` returns 1, and `sqlite3_errmsg` returns:

> "near "TABLE": syntax error"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put "TABLE" in your query :

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, "INSERT INTO  test VALUES (?,?,?,?)", -1, &stmt, 0);
if( rc!=SQLITE_OK )
    printf("%s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

it is also a good practice to name the fields you're inserting in. So that if you add fields to your table, your queries won't be broken...

Answer (score 2):

`TABLE` is a reserved keyword. To avoid syntax error, it must be escaped by using brackets,

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

- [SQLite Reserved Keywords with four ways of escaping it](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: Btw, `INSERT INTO [TABLE]` was still giving me an error, this time `syntax error near test`, but removing TABLE altogether fixed that error too and now it's returning success. Not it's only `INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?,?,?)`

Comment: at first I thought your table is called `Table` but I was wrong. your tablename is `test` right? So you should remove `table` instead.

Comment: Yes, my table is called `test`.